# Random class C# printing values the same each time application runs

Tags: c#, random

I would like to get random values using Random class the same each time application runs and only different when I change seed value or initialize random class.

I declare `Random random = new Random();` as a global parameter.

Then I print 3 random doubles:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
 Console.WriteLine(random.NextDouble())
```

Each time application runs I get different values

For instance first time I run application I get values
0.454, 0.256, 0.100

Second time
0.578, 0.123, 0.001

But what I would to have is that each time application runs I would get the same numbers

For example first time I run app I get
0.454, 0.256, 0.100
Second time
0.454, 0.256, 0.100

Comment: Maybe your implementation uses a random seed itself internally when you don't specify one (ex: using the current timestamp). Provide your own seed yourself if you want to make sure to get the same results every time

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx "Providing an identical seed value to different Random objects causes each instance to produce **identical sequences of random numbers**. This is often done when testing apps that rely on random number generators."

Comment: Um just what do you mean by 'global parameter'??? a class level variable, perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provide the random constructor with a seed such as 1, although it could be any number:

```
Random random = new Random(1);
```

Now each time you'll get the same number so it won't be random. If you don't provide it will by default take the current time stamp as the seed, so you can control the values by controlling the seed.

Here's a complete solution:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random(1);


            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(random.NextDouble());

            Console.Read();
        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
0.248668584157093
0.110743977181029
0.467010679872246
```

Comment: Maybe explain why the default constructor does not behave the same as supplying a constant seed

Comment: No it won't! If you get varying values from the same seed now you have hidden code somewhere!

Comment: Can it be that my application initializes each time application runs Random random = new Random(0); next time it will initialize new Random(0) again

Comment: let me put together a few lines of code to illustrate for you

Answer (score 3):

You could pick a hardcoded seed in your [`Random` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx).

When you initialize the `Random` class, do something like

```
var random = new Random(0);
```

The seed is the initial state of `Random`. By default, it depends on the system clock, so every time you initialize it in application runs, it gets a new seed and has different behavior. By picking a static seed, it will behave the same.

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize the Random class. Provide the constructor with the same seed.

Example:

```
Random random = new Random(0);
```

This will give you the same values every time you run the program.

This is because the default constructor provides a seed value that is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution.

Comment: This is a great comment but a poor answer. Try to thicken it a bit with some more data, perhaps a code sample.